Change multiple classes to be partial classes in Visual Studio
I was wondering if there was a way to fix all same compilation errors we can encounter in a C# project in Visual Studio. For example, I am currently encountering hundreds of the following errors (following a change):

CS0260    Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MYClass'; another partial declaration of this type exists

I need now to have all those classes partial.
So instead of manually adding all partials in each one of them myself, maybe Visual Studio could propose a feature to do it all at once?
I tried to create my own Python script to apply those changes, but inner classes, namespaces, etc., made it very difficult to create a reliable one.

VS is not going to change your classes to partial for you.

You can do it with Regex.
Although this is a bit risky, it might cause more errors than it solves.
But it does the job.
Steps to change your classes to partial classes:
First preform the same applicable steps but with "Find in files" (ctr + shift + f) to check which classes will be made partial.

Open up "Find and Replace in files" (ctr + shift + h).
Check Match case.
Check Use regular expressions.
Check Preserve case.
In Look In: Select Entire Project

Make sure that when you open the "Find and Replace in files" tab you are in the project that you want to change.
Select Entire Solution if you want it to apply everywhere, even riskier.


Enter the regular expression:

(?<!partial) class (TestClass|Dummy)(?:\s|$)
Replace (TestClass|Dummy) with your class names that you want to change to partial, add more if needed with the | operator.


Enter the replacement expression: " partial class $1 " .

the whitespace before partial and after the $1 are required.


Click Replace Next.

check that the replacement is correct.


If the first replacement is correct Click Replace All.

P.S.:

Rename your question to be about something like "Change multiple classes to be partial classes" this way it will get deleted i think.
VS won't create an extension like this, because it would have to be something like change class definition and then it would still be class by class. Because there are very little use cases where you would want to change all of you classes to be partial classes.


Thanks for your help. Indeed, it requires a double check, but it saved me a lot of time!
